# How to get required hash from a hash array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes of the form:

```
[{"status"=>"Unshipped", "city"=>"thane", "buyer_name"=>"abc", "name"=>"abc def", "countryCode"=>"IN", "payment_method"=>"COD", "order_type"=>"StandardOrder", "y_id"=>"r123", "phone"=>"12345", "state"=>"Maharashtra", "service"=>"Expedited", "address_1"=>"abc xyz", "address_2"=>"yyyy", "postalCode"=>"400607", "shipped_by_y"=>"false", "channel"=>"MFN", "amout"=>"350.00"}, {"status"=>"Unshipped", "city"=>"Chembur, Mumbai", "buyer_name"=>"xyz", "name"=>"xyz lmn", "countryCode"=>"IN", "payment_method"=>"Other", "order_type"=>"StandardOrder", "y_id"=>"r124", "phone"=>"12436", "state"=>"Maharashtra", "service"=>"Expedited", "address_1"=>"add 1", "address_2"=>"add 2", "postalCode"=>"400071", "shipped_by_y"=>"false", "channel"=>"MFN", "amout"=>"399.00"}]
```

From this array I want to select the element which has given value for the key `y_id`.
Eg. if I want to get the element with `'y_id' = 'r124'`, I should get :

```
{"status"=>"Unshipped", "city"=>"Chembur, Mumbai", "buyer_name"=>"xyz", "name"=>"xyz lmn", "countryCode"=>"IN", "payment_method"=>"Other", "order_type"=>"StandardOrder", "y_id"=>"r124", "phone"=>"12436", "state"=>"Maharashtra", "service"=>"Expedited", "address_1"=>"add 1", "address_2"=>"add 2", "postalCode"=>"400071", "shipped_by_y"=>"false", "channel"=>"MFN", "amout"=>"399.00"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
arr.find { |i| i['y_id] == *value* }
```

Which will iterate over your array of hashes, where `i` is any given hash. `Select` will return an array of objects where the block resolves to `true`.

So, for example if you passed in `r123` as *value*, it would return

```
{"status"=>"Unshipped", "city"=>"thane", "buyer_name"=>"abc", "name"=>"abc def", "countryCode"=>"IN", "payment_method"=>"COD", "order_type"=>"StandardOrder", "y_id"=>"r123", "phone"=>"12345", "state"=>"Maharashtra", "service"=>"Expedited", "address_1"=>"abc xyz", "address_2"=>"yyyy", "postalCode"=>"400607", "shipped_by_y"=>"false", "channel"=>"MFN", "amout"=>"350.00"}
```

to get the hash. (Thanks @BroiSatse)

Comment: `'y_id'`, not `:y_id`. :) Also assuming that `y_id` is unique it will be faster to use `find` instead of `select{..}.first`

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) API. It returns the first element which matches what you look for, or `nil` if none is found:

```
arr.find { |element| element['y_id'] == 'r124' }
```

will return:

```
{"status"=>"Unshipped", "city"=>"Chembur, Mumbai", "buyer_name"=>"xyz", "name"=>"xyz lmn", "countryCode"=>"IN", "payment_method"=>"Other", "order_type"=>"StandardOrder", "y_id"=>"r124", "phone"=>"12436", "state"=>"Maharashtra", "service"=>"Expedited", "address_1"=>"add 1", "address_2"=>"add 2", "postalCode"=>"400071", "shipped_by_y"=>"false", "channel"=>"MFN", "amout"=>"399.00"}
```